Describing geometrically the set of complex $z$ satisfying $\mathrm{Re} \left(\frac{z-a}{b}\right)>0$, for $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $b \neq 0$

Describe geometrically the set of complex numbers $z$ that satisfy:
$$\mathrm{Re} \left(\frac{z-a}{b}\right)>0$$
where $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $b \neq 0$.

I have thought about it, and I know that the real numbers $\mathrm{Re}(z) > 0$ are in the first and fourth quadrants, so a half-plane. I'm not sure how dividing by $b$ affects $\mathrm{Re}(z - a)$. Does it just rotate my half-plane by the angle of $b$? Subtracting with $a$, I think I understand, should just mean that we move the half-plane by the length of $a$.
If somebody could help me understand the relation to this problem, I would be very thankful! Sorry if my writing was unclear: English is not my first language.

its clear z-a is a complex number, lets divide 1/b into two cases, for b > 0, can you rewrite 1/b in terms of the exp function?

$Re(z) > 0$ implies that the argument of $z$ lies in the range $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$
$z-a$ can be visualized as a vector drawn from $a$ to $z$
Dividing by $b$ will rotate this vector by an angle equal and opposite to the argument of $b$
The magnitude of this vector also changes, but that is irrelevant to satisfying the condition
Hence, the set of all $z$ will be the half-plane to the right of $a$, rotated by $arg(b)$ about the point $a$

You can visualize this process in two steps. First, draw a vertical line through $a$. This divides the coordinate plane into two halves. Then rotate this line by an angle equal to the argument of $b$ (so that the effect of division by $b$ gets nullified). $z$ lies in the half-plane which would have originally been to the right of $a$ before the rotation.

Let $f(z)=\dfrac{z-a}{b}$. Then your problem is the same as finding the domain for which the function's range will be the half complex plane $Re(z) > 0$.Since the function $f(z)$ is bijective, the domain over which $\mathrm{Re}\{f(z)\}>0$ is the same as the range of the inverse function $f^{-1}(z)=bz+a$ over the domain $\mathrm{Re}\{z\}>0$. Figuring out the range would be much easier
Geometrically, $f^{-1}(z)=bz+a$ scales the complex plane by a factor of $|b|$ and rotates it by the angle $\arg(b)$, then shifts the plane by the vector $a$. And so the set you want to find is the image of $\mathrm{Re}\{z\}>0$ under those transformations.
